# How to load a font and render it with TextGeometry

Tags: javascript, three.js

I recently started working on three.js and now im facing issue on textgeometry.
Im using three.js version 75 and i used js/helvetiker_bold.typeface.js font.

```
var geometry = new THREE.TextGeometry( this.txt, {
  size: this.textSize,
  height: this.textHeight,
  curveSegments: 3,
  font: this.textFont,
  weight: "bold",
  style: "normal",
  bevelEnabled: false
});
```

test is not rendering because of the following issue

1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _typeface_js is not defined

2.three.min.js:889 THREE.TextGeometry: font parameter is not an instance of THREE.Font

Can anyone please help me out.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use a pattern like this one to load a font and render it with `TextGeometry`:

```js
import { FontLoader } from 'three/addons/loaders/FontLoader.js';
import { TextGeometry } from 'three/addons/geometries/TextGeometry.js';

...

const loader = new FontLoader();

loader.load( 'fonts/helvetiker_bold.typeface.json', function ( font ) {

    const textGeo = new TextGeometry( "My Text", {

        font: font,

        size: 200,
        height: 50,
        curveSegments: 12,

        bevelThickness: 2,
        bevelSize: 5,
        bevelEnabled: true

    } );

    const textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff0000 } );

    const mesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, textMaterial );
    mesh.position.set( 0, 0, 10 );

    scene.add( mesh );

} );
```

three.js r.147

Comment: i used this but text not visible.

Comment: Text not visible with `three.js r100`

Comment: where do you get the fonts??

Comment: @JustinMeskan you can find the fonts here https://unpkg.com/browse/three@0.77.0/examples/fonts/

Answer (score 6):

You don't need to use `FontLoader`, just load json as:

```
const fontJson = require( "./fonts/gentilis_bold.typeface.json" );

const font = new THREE.Font( fontJson );
```

Comment: If you use MeshPhongMaterial texture or others (except MeshBasicMaterial) you should add some lights to your scene. Just add this lines to your scene. 

`const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.5); pointLight.position.set(0, 100, 90);
scene.add(pointLight);
pointLight.color.setHSL(Math.random(), 1, 0.5);
const textMaterials = [
new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, flatShading: true }),
new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff }), ];`