# Issue with Mad Dog ThreeJS Tutorial 5

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am going through the video series of Mad Dog tutorials on ThreeJS, and I am having an issue getting tutorial 5 to work in any of my browsers.  The title is:

Three Spot Light THREE.js Spot Light Test

and JavaScript code is at the URL:

http://wpdildine.github.io/blog/2015/03/10/THREE-Spot-Light/

The HTML code is set up correctly, and works correctly with the earlier tutorial.  My HTML code is just:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Our WebGL Skeleton Framework</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dat-gui/0.5.1/dat.gui.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/OrbitControls.js"></script>
  <style>
    body {margin: 0; overflow: hidden;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="webGL-container"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and I copied the JavaScript code to the main.js from the link above.

Firefox shows a small black rectangle in the upper left of the window with the controls to the right, but nothing else.  Both Google Chrome and Opera fill the window with a black background and the controls on the right, but nothing else.  IE 10 and Safari don't work at all and just show a blank white screen, but they also don't work with WebGL, as I'm not particularly concerned about these two at the moment.

My main concern is that Firefox, Chrome and Opera don't work, and would be grateful to know how to fix this issue.  I'm new to ThreeJS so I'm still learning and it's frustrating when something like this happens, so any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: OK, thanks, I've just checked with the console and 2 errors are flagged: (1) THREE.TextGeometry: font parameter is not an instance of THREE.Font., (2) ReferenceError: Stats is not defined.  Thus there appears to be a problem with my ThreeJS library I'm using, which is revision 76.

Comment: No, it more than likely means you implemented the library incorrectly. _" font parameter is not an instance of THREE.Font"_ means you didnt pass TextGeometry the correct type of font (instance of THREE.Font). The other one just means something tried to use a variable named `Stats` but apparently it was never defined.

Comment: Well in fact I tried three.js r70 with https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r70/three.js and these errors have gone.  However, I now get the error: TypeError: THREE.Spherical is not a constructor in the file OrbitControls.js.

Comment: I've gone back to ThreeJS r76 and get the 2 original errors.  The app tries to do something, and the controls are shown, which is not the case with r70.  I note that error: "THREE.TextGeometry: font parameter is not an instance of THREE.Font." is generated in three.js in the condition: if ( font instanceof THREE.Font === false ).  I passed it no font, and assume a default is used, but even if I try to pass a font using lower case, it still fails.  Once this is resolved I will look at the 2nd error.

Comment: I discovered that Stats is no longer in Three.js, which explains the 2nd error.  By downloading https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/ fixed that and the stats are now shown.  I also discovered that THREE.TextGeometry() needs a font, and after copying some of the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676274/how-to-load-a-font-and-render-it-with-textgeometry and making some changes, then downloading helvetiker_regular.typeface.js also fixes the other error.  However, I'm now getting the error: "_typeface_js is not defined", but at least some of the scene is being rendered.