# Error with TextGeometry for write text in webgl

Tags: javascript, three.js

I usually used TextGeometry to write a text in webgl context, but I have an error (helvetiker_bold.typeface.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: _typeface_js is not defined) like this issue [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/7360). So people said TextGeometry API changed again and its better use "THREE.FontLoader()" like this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676274/how-to-load-a-font-and-render-it-with-textgeometry).

But I have another error in my code, so the error output is:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///home/douglas/Projetos/SDCampE/view/fonts/helvetiker_bold.typeface.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: HTTP, data, chrome, chrome-extension, HTTPS, chrome-extension-resource.

Should I create a server for this file? I try to input font by JSON files and normal JavaScript files and I have the same error.

Is there other way to write a simple 3D text in WebGL?

I tried running `chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files` but the error continues.

This is my code:

```
var loader = new THREE.FontLoader();
loader.load( 'view/fonts/helvetiker_bold.typeface.json', function ( font ) {
    var textGeo = new THREE.TextGeometry( "THREE.JS", {
        font: font,
        size: 200,
        height: 50,
        curveSegments: 12,
        bevelThickness: 2,
        bevelSize: 5,
        bevelEnabled: true
    });
    textGeo.computeBoundingBox();
    var centerOffset = -0.5 * ( textGeo.boundingBox.max.x - textGeo.boundingBox.min.x );
    var textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { color: 0xff0000, specular: 0xffffff } );
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( textGeo, textMaterial );
    mesh.position.x = centerOffset;
    mesh.position.y = FLOOR + 67;
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    scene.add( mesh );
```

Comment: You [need to run a simple server](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/webgl/2605/getting-started-with-webgl/8648/installation-or-setup#t=201704180423409905419). I'd recommend [servez](https://greggman.github.io/servez/).

Comment: Thanks, I used [servez](https://greggman.github.io/servez/). It's a nice project!