# Text isn't rendered correctly using TextGeometry (Three.js)

Tags: javascript, three.js

I was trying to render text in three.js using TextGeometry but got an empty black screen. I suspected that was an issue with the camera and I added simple green box, that box was rendered correctly.

```
// tslint:disable-next-line:no-var-requires
const fontJson = require("./fonts/gentilis_bold.typeface.json");
import "./index.scss";

import * as THREE from "three";
(window as any).THREE = THREE;
import "./controls/OrbitControls";

const scene = new THREE.Scene();

const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 5);
camera.lookAt(scene.position);

const textMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
console.log(new THREE.Font(fontJson))
const textGeometry = new THREE.TextGeometry("Hello amigo", {
  font: new THREE.Font(fontJson),
  size: 80,
  height: 5,
  curveSegments: 12,
  bevelEnabled: true,
  bevelThickness: 10,
  bevelSize: 8,
});
const textMesh = new THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial);

// const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1);
// const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
// const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
// scene.add(mesh);

scene.add(textMesh);

const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
controls.addEventListener("change", () => {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
});

renderer.render(scene, camera);
```

[image]

Comment: Three.js version
THREE.WebGLRenderer 89

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36676274/how-to-load-a-font-and-render-it-with-textgeometry

Comment: Does it really necessary? In three.js source code we have simple ajax request and parse method
  parse: function ( json ) {
   return new Font( json );
  },
var font = scope.parse( json );
if ( onLoad ) onLoad( font );
I do the same but without using FileLoader.

Comment: I have found the problem. The problem was connected with MeshPhongMaterial, just change THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, textMaterial) to THREE.Mesh(textGeometry, undefined).

Comment: Do you understand why?

Comment: @WestLangley Of course, I have found the problem, sorry for the delay. If you use MeshPhongMaterial texture or others (except MeshBasicMaterial) you should add some lights to your scene. Just add this lines to your scene.

`const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.5);
pointLight.position.set(0, 100, 90);
scene.add(pointLight);
pointLight.color.setHSL(Math.random(), 1, 0.5);

const textMaterials = [
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, flatShading: true }),
  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff }),
];`

Comment: Correct. So you can now provide the answer to your question: `MeshPhongMaterial` requires scene lights.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem, sorry for the delay. If you use MeshPhongMaterial texture or others (except MeshBasicMaterial) you should add some lights to your scene. Just add this lines to your scene.

```
const pointLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff, 1.5); pointLight.position.set(0, 100, 90);
scene.add(pointLight);
pointLight.color.setHSL(Math.random(), 1, 0.5);
const textMaterials = [
new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff, flatShading: true }),
new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xffffff }),
];
```